# If I provide to a function one dict two times and then del key in one of the dict, for some reason the same key are deleted in the 2nd dict. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Test function:

```
def test_dicts(first_dict, second_dict):
    print('\nbefore first_dict_:', first_dict)
    print('before second_dict:', second_dict)

    del second_dict[2]

    print('\nafter first_dict_:', first_dict)
    print('after second_dict:', second_dict)
```

Test data:

```
dicts = {1: {11:11}, 2: {22:22}}
```

Lets test:

```
>>> tmp.test_dicts(dicts, dicts)

before first_dict_: {1: {11: 11}, 2: {22: 22}}
before second_dict: {1: {11: 11}, 2: {22: 22}}

after first_dict_: {1: {11: 11}}
after second_dict: {1: {11: 11}}
```

`del second_dict[2]` clearly says to delete the key from the `second_dict`, but for some reason Python deletes also this key from the `first_dict`. Why does it happen?

Comment: where and how is defined `dicts2`?

Comment: You don't show how you create `dicts2`. Is it `dicts2 = dicts`, by any chance?

Comment: @TitanFighter you are pointing to the same object in memory. You shouold rather copy the dict before passing it as a second argument.

Comment: @efkin, sorry, my mistake. Fixed. It should be the same dict.

Comment: @efkin, I thought about `the same object in memory`. Does it mean that Python does not care about variable names?

Comment: 8@TitanFighter the *same object* can have *zero or more **names*** - where that object is *mutable* (as is a `dict` or a `list` or a `set` etc...) - since all the names refer to the same object, any changes made to the underlying object via any of the names are seen from any names referring to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to attempt an answer.

```
>>> a = "hello"
>>> b = a
>>> bool(id(a) == id(b))
True
```

So even if they have different variable names, they are still the same object.

Comment: Agree. This simple example reminded me about this feature. Thanks.